# Drupal 7 - can't upload files

Tags: file, file-upload, drupal, drupal-7

I'm getting an error when trying to upload any type of file via Content>Files>Add File. The error reads "The file *filename* could not be saved. An unknown error has occurred. The file in the Upload a new file field was unable to be uploaded."

I've read through many threads and most seem to indicate a permissions problem. I've checked that all directories are configured properly. Public files are set as sites/default/files; private files are set as sites/default/files/private; and temporary is set as sites/default/files/tmp.

Then I found this error in the server logs:

[Tue Mar 27 10:49:26.932464 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 20750:tid 140070898026240] [client nn.nnn.nn.nn:63784] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0\n', referer: http://*ipaddress.com*/file/add

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Thanks,
CJ

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a permissions issue.

You mention the path of the different folders (public, private, and tmp), but that is a completely different thing.

What you need to check is that user running the webserver has permissions to write on those aforementioned folders.

Now, you don't mention what server are you using, so I'll assume you're running Apache, and the Apache user and group is called `apache` in CentOS and `www-data` in Ubuntu.

You should navigate to those folders (actually to the folder where this folders are placed) and type a `ls -la` sentence in the terminal, to get a list of permissions for them, as well as the name of the user that owns the folders.

The Apache user needs to access and **write** in those folders.

Comment: Thanks versus. I don't have terminal access to the server only Plesk access. But I will ask the server admin to investigate the owner of the folders.

Comment: Glad to help. If this helped you or solved the issue, please mark the question as answered for future visitors to know :)

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the similar problem once. Solution to this problem is to give the 'write' permission to 'others' as well on tmp directory. You might wonder that this is /tmp directory I am talking about, as while uploading a file it must pass through /tmp directory to the desired location.

So give the write (other) permission to /tmp and sites/default/files/tmp directory. Hope this will help.